# How to fix a sudden CDbException on Yii Framework after reboot (Active Record queries not working)

Tags: sql, yii

I'm currently following the steps of the book **"Agile Web Application Development with Yii"**, and so far I managed to get everything done and right, by Chapter 8. But now, **after I turned off and on** my laptop (upgraded my laptop's RAM), everything seems to work right except that **Active Record can't find database tables**, not only inside this webapp, but also tried with old functional and very simple demos I had, and none of them are working when Model classes (which extend the CActiveRecord class from Yii).

I'm using XAMPP, with a MySQL database (which works perfectly) on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3 (2.4GHz Intel Core 2 Duo, 8GB RAM MacBook Pro). PHPUnit was also working perfectly before reboot.

I've already checked my **'db' component** in my main.php file several times, and -I think- everything's fine:

```
'db'=>array(
    'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Customer',
    'emulatePrepare' => true,
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'jasalo',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
),
```

Also tried adding the

```
'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_'
```

parameter which is the one the book uses in its webapp (although it never recommends to do that, using a tablePrefix).

On the other hand, when I perform a **simple query** through Yii, it does work (I tried this on a simple view, About):

```
var_dump(Yii::app()->db->createCommand('select * from tbl_user')->queryAll());
```

And this is, part of, the result I get (which is correct):

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(9) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["email"]=> string(22) "test1@notanaddress.com" ["username"]=> string(13) "Test_User_One" ["password"]=> string(32) "5a105e8b9d40e1329780d62ea2265d8a"...
```

I even tried changing the framework path on Yii, located in the **index.php** file of the webapp, thinking that maybe the other. **Any ideas?**

Oh, and this is the error message I get whenever I try to use CActiveRecord models (classes):

```
CDbException

The table "tbl_user" for active record class "User" cannot be found in the database.
```

Comment: What does your models' tableName method return? Is it the actual table name, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my development environment (MAMP) having the following in my model worked:

```
public function tableName()
{
    return 'Nantivdb';
}
```

where 'Nantivdb' is the name of my class extending CActiveRecord and the table I query is 'nantiv0'.

Once in production I had to change for:

```
public function tableName()
{
    return 'nantiv0';
}
```

Or yii wouldn't find table 'nantiv0'.

Thus I'll make the following change in /models/User.php:

```
public function tableName()
{
    return 'tbl_user';
}
```

Sorry not to have more explanation to provide...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although my problem was a bit different. In your case, the function `tableName()`, if I'm not wrong, must always return exactly the name of the related table of your Model as it is on your Database, not the name of the class itself.
As of my problem, it was a permissions issue related just to my system settings, and even though I don't know exactly what I did wrong before, I solved it by changing the permissions on `/var/folders/` folder. You can have a look at the answer I made to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I found it was a permissions issue. I just found out the issue by going to phpmyadmin, logging in an trying to view a table's structure it said it didn't have permissions to access /var/folders so I just changed its permissions to 777 (a bit unsecure though, but not a problem in my case because it's on a single user environment):

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/folders
```